# React Native doesn't install specific version 0.67 , but install 0.68(latest) version

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-windows

When I try to start a project with a typescript template and specific version,for example: 0.67.4 doesn´t install this version, but install the latest version 0.68.

[image]

System: 
OS: Windows 10 10.0.19044 
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz 
Memory: 2.12 GB / 11.87 GB 
Binaries: 
Node: 16.14.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
Yarn: 1.22.17 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\yarn.CMD 
npm: 8.3.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `--template` already uses a version, the one of the template, thus `--version` has no effect. You need to specify the correct typescript template version for the correct react-native version. For `0.67.X` this is `6.9.*` which is documented [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-template-typescript).

Thus, the following should work.

```js
npx react-native init RNCComponents --template react-native-template-typescript@6.9.6
```

Do not ask me why it is `6.9.6` rather than `6.9.4`, but this one was `0.67.2` rather than `0.67.4`.